# python bypassing binary if statement and issuing all 0's

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to create binary values (0, 1) in a dataset and python is completely bypassing the if statements and I'm not sure why. I'm assuming my syntax is incorrect, but I have no idea what to do.

Example code:

```
df['Binary'] = 0

for row in df['standard_deviation']:
if row > 2: #greater than 2 standard deviations
    df['Binary'] = 1
else
    df['Binary'] = 0
```

expected output: Binary should come out with 0's and 1's, but instead it's issuing all 0's to the data.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

EDIT: Prints of "row" value. [Row from dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AeZO6.png)

Comment: Presumably the reason is that `row > 2` is never true. Have you checked the value of `row` by using a debugger or by adding `print(row)`?

Comment: @mkrieger1 Row is displaying correctly. I have edited OP with an image of row.

Comment: Please create a [mre] that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: This overwrites the same field over and over.

Comment: Have you tried to see what `df['Binary'] = 99` does? Try it. Then the problem should become obvious. In any case, **you shouldn't be looping over pandas data structures like this**, instead, just do `df['Binary'] = df['standard_deviation'] > 2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what you want to do, it's for the `'Binary'` column to contain a 1 or 0 for each row, depending on the value of the `'standard_deviation'` column for each row.

But instead by writing `df['Binary'] = 0` or `1` you are just assigning that value you to the entire column.

What you want in this case is simply:

```py
df['Binary'] = (df['standard_deviation'] > 2).astype('uint8')
```